# Jquery script only targeting first prepended element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, selector, prepend

why is the following script targeting only the first element

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".edit_post_tab").click(function () {
          var utility_id = $(this).attr("rel");
          $(this).siblings("#post_utilities" + utility_id).toggle();
      });
  });
```

HTML/PHP:(the following is receieved through another page)

```
<div class="edit_post_tab" rel="'.$rand_id.'"></div>
<div class="post_utilities" id="post_utilities'.$rand_id.'" style="display:none;">
  <div class="post_utilities-arrow"></div>
  <div class="post_utilities-window">
      <div id="post_utility" class="tab1-post" rel="'.$rand_id.'">Edit my post</div>
      <div id="post_utility" class="tab2-post" rel="'.$rand_id.'">Delete my post</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

MY QUESTION:
the problem i face is that when i post the data and prepend it it works fine but when two prepended elements exist the jquery selector only targets the first of the twoprepended elements.when i refresh the page the problem disappears

Comment: Can you put in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @JFit cant put it js fiddle does not have a php option besides the problem disappears when the page is reloaded ie. the problem exists only when the two divs exist in an prepended state